# Different Result of JSP executeQuery() and MSMS in the same queries

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

I am working with the tomcat, jsp, and MSSQL 2008, and want to get some summary data such as Daily, Weekly, Monthly and Yearly.
From here, I searched how to use the datapart() function for these summary data from MSSQL.
In JSP, I used

```
PreparedStatement pr = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs=pr.executeQuery();
```

and in MSMS, queried directry for test.

I met two problems from my JSP program, but worked well in the MS SQL Server Management Studio with same queries.

[This is a screenshot of query result in MSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97qXa.png)

My problems are:

- query for "Yearly" are not working at the JSP.
- In query for "Monthly", Month values(1,2,3,...) are not returned
  correctly, but only 0(zero).

"Daily" and "Weekly" are working well. How can I solve these problems?
Thanks in advance.

my queries are:

```
switch (unit)
{
    case "Daily"        :
        query = "SELECT cast(datepart(dy, ProcessDate) as varchar(3)) Day, " + 
                    "cast(year(ProcessDate) as varchar(4)) Year, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) InWarranty, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) OutOfWarranty, " +
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) NAWarranty " +
                    "FROM zz_RMA_Summary " +
                    "WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN '" + sDate + "' AND '" + eDate + "' " +
                    "group by year(ProcessDate), datepart(dy, ProcessDate) " +
                    "order by year(ProcessDate) DESC, datepart(dy, ProcessDate) DESC ";
        break;

    case "Weekly"       :   
        query = "SELECT cast(datepart(wk, ProcessDate) as varchar(2)) Week, " + 
                    "cast(year(ProcessDate) as varchar(4)) Year, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) InWarranty, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) OutOfWarranty, " +
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) NAWarranty " +
                    "FROM zz_RMA_Summary " +
                    "WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN '" + sDate + "' AND '" + eDate + "' " +
                    "group by year(ProcessDate), datepart(wk, ProcessDate) " +
                    "order by year(ProcessDate) DESC, datepart(wk, ProcessDate) DESC ";
        break;

    case "Monthly"      :
        query = "SELECT cast(datepart(mm, ProcessDate) as varchar(2)) Month, " + 
                    "cast(year(ProcessDate) as varchar(4)) Year, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) InWarranty, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) OutOfWarranty, " +
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) NAWarranty " +
                    "FROM zz_RMA_Summary " +
                    "WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN '" + sDate + "' AND '" + eDate + "' " +
                    "group by year(ProcessDate), datepart(mm, ProcessDate) " +
                    "order by year(ProcessDate) DESC, datepart(mm, ProcessDate) DESC ";
        break;

    case "Yearly"       :
        query = "SELECT cast(yyyyy, ProcessDate) as varchar(4)) Year, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) InWarranty, " + 
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) OutOfWarranty, " +
                    "SUM(case WHEN Warranty = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) NAWarranty " +
                    "FROM zz_RMA_Summary " +
                    "WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN '" + sDate + "' AND '" + eDate + "' " +
                    "group by datepart(yyyy, ProcessDate) " +
                    "order by datepart(yyyy, ProcessDate) DESC ";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by `dates` that you pass as `strings`, that is wrong.

Why do you use dynamic sql, is it mandatory?

Can you use it with `parameters` (of `date` type) and not with `string` concatenation?

If you insists on your string concatenation, you should use [convert()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx)
function with the appropriate style to pass in your date strings, alternatively, pass your dates in `yyyymmdd` format without any separators, that will bring you to consistent results.

What happens now is or your application supplies `date`s in another format than you use in SSMS, or your application just uses another `login` that has different `default language`.

Login's default language is then inherited by session and it affects how date constants are interpreted.

Here is an example:

```
declare @t table (dt datetime);
insert into @t values ('20170110'), ('20171001'); -- Jan, 10; Oct, 1st

set language british -- this happens when my login's default language is us_english 
select *
from @t 
where dt between '01/09/2017' and '01/01/2018' -- I'm in Europe an I want the dates starting from Sept, 1st 
---
dt
2017-10-01 00:00:00.000 -- I'm happy with correct result



set language us_english -- this happens when my login's default language is us_english 
select *
from @t 
where dt between '01/09/2017' and '01/01/2018' -- I'm in Europe an I want the dates starting from Sept, 1st 
----
dt
2017-01-10 00:00:00.000 -- quite strange since I filtered starting from September
2017-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

But all this will not happen if instead of `between '01/09/2017' and '01/01/2018'` you use `between '20170901' and '20180101'` that is `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: Thank you, sepupic. Your advice was not conclusive, but it allowed me to get the answer. In "Monthly" and "Yearly" portion, there are some wrong codes in JSP.